# How can I modify an "if condition" in order to apply it to different list at the same time?

Tags: python, list, spacy

I wrote a script to extract sentences in huge set which contains particular pattern. The problem lied in the fact that , for some patterns I checked the value of the attribute at the beginning or ending of the pattern to see if the word is present in a particular list. I have 4 dictionaries with 2 lists of positive and negative word. So far I wrote the script and I am able to use the function I wrote with one dictionary. I am thinking how can I improve the my function so that I can use it at the same time of the 4 dictionaries without duplicating the bloc which loop in the dictionary.

I give an example with two dictionaries (since the script is quite long I make a small example with all the necessary element

```
import spacy.attrs
from spacy.attrs import POS
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.lang.fr import French
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_infix_regex, compile_suffix_regex
from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer
nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_md")
from spacy.matcher import Matcher#LIST 


##################### List of lexicon

# Lexique Diko
lexicon = open(os.path.join('/h/Ressources/Diko.txt'), 'r', encoding='utf-8')
data = pd.read_csv(lexicon, sep=";", header=None)
data.columns = ["id", "terme", "pol"]
pol_diko_pos = data.loc[data.pol =='positive', 'terme']
liste_pos_D = list(pol_diko_pos)
print(liste_pos[1])
pol_diko_neg = data.loc[data.pol =='negative', 'terme']
liste_neg_D = list(pol_diko_neg)
#print(type(liste_neg))


# Lexique Polarimots
lexicon_p = open(os.path.join('/h/Ressources/polarimots.txt'), 'r', encoding='utf-8')
data_p = pd.read_csv(lexicon_p, sep="\t", header=None)
#data.columns = ["terme", "pol", "pos", "degre"]
data_p.columns = ["ind", "terme", "cat", "pol", "fiabilité"]
pol_polarimot_pos = data_p.loc[data_p.pol =='POS', 'terme']
liste_pos_P = list(pol_polarimot_pos)
print(liste_pos_P[1])
pol_polarimot_neg = data_p.loc[data_p.pol =='NEG', 'terme']
liste_neg_P = list(pol_polarimot_neg)
#print(type(liste_neg))


# #############################     Lists 

sentence_not_extract_lexique_1 =[] #List of all sentences without the specified pattern
sentence_extract_lexique_1 = [] #list of sentences which the pattern[0] is present in the first lexicon

sentence_not_extract_lexique_2 =[] #List of all sentences without the specified pattern
sentence_extract_lexique_2 = [] #list of sentences which the pattern[0] is present in the second lexicon

list_token_pos = [] #list of the token found in the lexique
list_token_neg = [] #list of the token found in the lexique
list_token_not_found = [] #list of the token not found in the lexique

#PATTERN 

pattern1 = [{"POS": {"IN": ["VERB", "AUX","ADV","NOUN","ADJ"]}}, {"IS_PUNCT": True, "OP": "*"}, {"LOWER": "mais"} ] 

pattern1_tup = (pattern1, 1, True)

pattern3 = [{"LOWER": {"IN": ["très","trop"]}},
           {"POS": {"IN": ["ADV","ADJ"]}}]

pattern3_tup = (pattern3, 0, True)

pattern4 = [{"POS": "ADV"},  # adverbe de négation
            {"POS": "PRON","OP": "*"},
            {"POS": {"IN": ["VERB", "AUX"]}}, 
            {"TEXT": {"IN": ["pas", "plus", "aucun", "aucunement", "point", "jamais", "nullement", "rien"]}},]

pattern4_tup = (pattern4, None, False)

#Tuple of pattern

pattern_list_tup =[pattern1_tup, pattern3_tup, pattern4_tup]
pattern_name = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
length_of_list = len(pattern_list_tup)
print('length', length_of_list)

#index of the value of attribute to check in the lexicon

value_of_attribute = [0,-1,-1]

# List of lexicon to use 

lexique_1 = [lexique_neg, lexique_pos]
lexique_2 = [lexique_2neg, lexique_2pos]


# text (example of some sentences)

file =b= ["Le film est superbe mais cette édition DVD est nulle !",
    "J'allais dire déplorable, mais je serais peut-être un peu trop extrême.",
    "Hélas, l'impression de violence, bien que très bien rendue, ne sauve pas cette histoire gothique moderne de la sécheresse scénaristique, le tout couvert d'un adultère dont le propos semble être gratuit, classique mais intéressant...",
    "Tout ça ne me donne pas envie d'utiliser un pieu mais plutôt d'aller au pieu (suis-je drôle).",
"Oui biensur, il y a la superbe introduction des parapluies au debut, et puis lorsqu il sent des culs tout neufs et qu il s extase, j ai envie de faire la meme chose apres sur celui de ma voisine de palier (ma voisine de palier elle a un gros cul, mais j admets que je voudrais bien lui foute mon tarin), mais c est tout, apres c est un film tres noir, lent et qui te plonge dans le depression.",
"Et bien hélas ce DVD ne m'a pas appris grand chose par rapport à la doc des agences de voyages et la petite dame qui fait ses dessins est bien gentille mais tout tourne un peu trop autour d'elle.",
"Au final on passe de l'un a l'autre sans subtilité, et on n'arrive qu'à une caricature de plus : si Kechiche avait comme but initial déclaré de fustiger les préjugés, c'est le contraire qui ressort de ce ''film'' truffé de clichés très préjudiciables pour les quelques habitants de banlieue qui ne se reconnaîtront pas dans cette lourde farce.",
"-ci écorche les mots, les notes... mais surtout nos oreilles !"]



# Loop to check each sentence and extract the sentences with the specified pattern from above

for pat in range(0, length_of_list):
    matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)  
    matcher.add("matching_2", None, pattern_list_tup[pat][0])
    # print(pat)
    # print(pattern_list_tup[pat][0])
    for sent in file:
        doc =nlp(sent)
        matches= matcher(doc)
        for match_id, start, end in matches:    
                    span = doc[start:end].lemma_.split()
                    #print(f"{pattern_name[pat]} pattern found: {span}")
```

This is the part I want ot modify to use it for another dictionary, the goal is to able to retrieve sentences extract by 4 different dictionaries to make a comparison and then check which sentences are present in more than two list.

```
 # Condition to use the lexicon and extract the sentence
                    
                    if (pattern_list_tup[pat][2]):
                        if (span[value_of_attribute[pat]] in lexique_1[pattern_list_tup[pat][1]]):
                            if sent not in sentence_extract:
                                sentence_extract_lexique_1.append(sent)
                            if (pattern_list_tup[pat][1] == 1):
                                list_token_pos.append(span[value_of_attribute[pat]])
                            if (pattern_list_tup[pat][1] == 0):
                                list_token_neg.append(span[value_of_attribute[pat]])
                        else:
                            list_token_not_found.append(span[value_of_attribute[pat]])  # the text form is not present in the lexicon need the lemma form
                            sentence_not_extract_lexique_1.append(sent)
                    else:
                        if sent not in sentence_extract:
                            sentence_extract_lexique_1.append(sent)
                    
print(len(sentence_extract))
print(sentence_extract)
```

One solution I find is to duplicate the code abode and change the name of the list where the sentences are stored but since I have 2 dictionaries duplicating will make the code longer is there a way to combine the looping the 2 dictionaries (actually 4 dictionaries in the original) and append the result to the good list. So, for example, when I use lexique_1 , all the sentences extracted are send to "sentence_extract_lexique_1" and so on for the other.

Comment: What is the question? [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: @wwii Please explain yourself because I do not get it ?

Comment: It is a Q&A site. What is your question, are you asking someone to refactor your code for you? Please read [ask]. caveat: I don't know `spacy` and am not versed in nlp so maybe I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion attempt using the if-elif-else chain. If not attempt only using the if-elif block simply because the elif statement catches the specific condition of interest. In which you're trying to catch a specific to compare and check with the sentences. Keep in mind if you try the if-elif-else chain its a good method, but it only works when you need one test to pass. Because Python finds one test to pass and it skips the rest. Its very efficient and allows you to test for one specific condition.